# How do I convert Python crawled Bing web page content to human-readable?

Tags: python, python-requests, web-crawler, search-engine, bing

I'm playing with crawling Bing web search page using python.
I find the raw content received looks like byte type, but the attempt to decompress it has failed.
Does someone have clue what kind of data is this, and how should I extract readable from this raw content? Thanks!

My code displayed the raw content and then tried to do the gunzip, so you could see the raw content as well as error from the decompression.
Due to the raw content is too long, I just paste the first a few lines in below.

**Code:**

```
import urllib.request as Request
import gzip

req = Request.Request('www.bing.com')
req.add_header('upgrade-insecure-requests', 1)
res = Request.urlopen(req).read()
print("RAW Content: %s" %ResPage) # show raw content of web
print("Try decompression:")
print(gzip.decompress(ResPage))   # try decompression
```

**Result:**

```
RAW Content: b'+p\xe70\x0bi{)\xee!\xea\x88\x9c\xd4z\x00Tgb\x8c\x1b\xfa\xe3\xd7\x9f\x7f\x7f\x1d8\xb8\xfeaZ\xb6\xe3z\xbe\'\x7fj\xfd\xff+\x1f\xff\x1a\xbc\xc5N\x00\xab\x00\xa6l\xb2\xc5N\xb2\xdek\xb9V5\x02\t\xd0D \x1d\x92m%\x0c#\xb9>\xfbN\xd7\xa7\x9d\xa5\xa8\x926\xf0\xcc\'\x13\x97\x01/-\x03... ...

Try decompression:
Traceback (most recent call last):
OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'+p')


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to get started with the requests library. Plus, this is also the most commonly used lib for http requests nowadays.

Install requests in your python environment:

```
pip install requests
```

In your .py file:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.bing.com")

print(r.text)
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried your code and it only output '<Response [200]>', but it's better than a lot of binary codes. So is there a way to get normal home page content from the way you have pointed?

Comment: I guess you just printed request object, something like this: print(r)

Comment: @sylph001 Yeah, as Federico pointed out. You need to print(r.text) or print(r.content)

Answer (score 1):

```
OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'+p')
```

You either need to add [`"accept-encoding: "gzip"` or `"br"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding#syntax) to request `headers` or read content-encoding from the response and choose the correct one, or use `requests` library instead that will do everything for you.

The second problem that might appear, you need to pass a `user-agent` to request `headers` to act as a "real" user visit.

If no `user-agent` is being passed into request `headers` while using `requests` library it defaults to [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) so Bing or other search engine understands that it's a bot/script, and blocks a request. Check [what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

Pass `user-agent` using `requests` library:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}

requests.get('URL', headers=headers)
```

[How to reduce the chance of being blocked while web scraping search engines](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/how-to-reduce-chance-being-blocked-while-web-scraping-search-engines-1o46).

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Bing Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/bing-organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that you don't have to spend time trying to bypass blocks from Bing or other search engines or figure out different tedious problems such as picking the correct `CSS` selector if the HTML layout is not the best out there.

Instead, focus on the data that needs to be extracted from the structured JSON. Check out the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.